# How to edit data in XAML data source

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, datasource

I'm working on a windows phone 7 application. When my application starts, it should load data from a XAML file data source I've created using Expression Blend.

I decided to put my data in a XAML file because it is easy to bind to a Listbox, and also because Expression Blend allows me to edit my XAML data file in a convenient way using a grid view. This helps me a lot as I need to manually enter initial data needed for my application.

However, I want to be able to dynamically modify the values of objects stored in the XAML data source file during run-time and save them to this same XAML file, so that next time when the application starts, it can load the new modified data from it. How can I do this? Or if you have better suggestions of storing data locally please do share them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [XamlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx) and [XamlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlwriter.aspx).

Maybe I have an example somewhere. I should try to track it down.

Comment: I tracked down the sample project and put the code up for you.http://www.wpfsharp.com/2012/12/05/loading-or-saving-a-xaml-resource-dictionary/